# How to manage deployments to multiple non-clustered tomcat instances

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat

What is the best way to manage deployments of a single web-app to multiple non-clustered tomcat instances.

My ideal solution will support:

- A simple API - invoked with
  groovy/ant/Rest or similar
- Success/failure
  notification for all nodes
- Atomic
  deployments - if the deployments
  fails on any node it is rolled back.

Answer (score 1):

We had over 100 clients each running on a dedicated tomcat instance across 5 servers where most would be updated to the latest release at the same time. In our case we used mapped network drives and some tricks with the CATALINA_BASE, but personally I think it may be easier to use WAR deployment via an ANT script to the Tomcat manager if you can get away with it.
For yours you could (at minimum) have a tomcat directory for each instance and each can use the same webapps dir via a network share. Upgrading would still require stopping each instance, updating the single shared dir then starting all instances.
You could also use the tomcat management console (via ANT or other automated process) to manage a scripted local installation or start/stop but this would be not be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [using Tomcat manager from Ant](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html#Executing_Manager_Commands_With_Ant). It might not have all you are asking for, but I guess you could script what you need.